# I am not able to get any output on the browser

Tags: python, pysimplegui

This piece of code calculates the shift that the user will be on a given date. 3 x Shifts (Morning, Evening, Night) rotating every 5 weeks. Each shift has 2 x teams of techs. 1st team works on a Sun-Thu rotation 2nd team works on a Tue-Sat rotation

A GUI has been implemented with PySimpleGUI in order to make the code more user friendly.
I tried running this in my web browser using PySipmleGUIWeb.

Starting the app in the browser I have no issues choosing the Day, shift etc. As soon as I hit the submit button nothing happens actually and I get the following output in the Pycharm console:

```
Returned from Remi Start command... now sending None event
```

Tried to get rid of the popup windows for the results and tried to just print them. I got no error but only the results in the PyCharm console instead of the web browser.

Any idea on how to make this work using the PySimpleGUIWeb?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
import datetime
import math
import calendar
import PySimpleGUIWeb as sg
import traceback

layout = [
          [sg.Text("Please enter your Current Shift and the date you would like to check what rotation you will be.")],
          [sg.Text("Current Shift", size=(15, 1)), sg.Checkbox("Morning", key="morning"), sg.Checkbox("Evening", key="evening"), sg.Checkbox("Night", key="night")],
          [sg.Text("First day Off", size=(15, 1)), sg.Combo(["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], key="Day_Off")],
          [sg.Text("Date YYYY.MM.DD", size=(18, 1)), sg.InputText("Date in YYYY.MM.DD format", key="Date")],
          [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
         ]
window = sg.Window("Shift Rotation", layout=layout, background_color="#272533", size=(600, 150), web_start_browser=True)

try:
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        window.close()
        if event is None:
            break
        if event == "Cancel":
            break
        if event == "Submit":

            def Days_Off():
                week = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"]
                Dayoff2 = week[week.index(Dayoff1.lower())+1]
                DayOffCheck = calendar.day_name[date1.weekday()]
                if Dayoff1.lower() == DayOffCheck.lower() or Dayoff2.lower() == DayOffCheck.lower():
                    sg.popup("Hey it is {}! You got the day off!".format(DayOffCheck))
                else:
                    sg.popup("It is {}! You are working on that day!".format(DayOffCheck))

            def Morning():
                Morning = []
                Evening = []
                Night = []
                x = 1
                y = 2
                z = 3
                for i in range(99999):
                    Morning.append(float(x + 3 * i))
                    Evening.append(float(y + 3 * i))
                    Night.append(float(z + 3 * i))
                if ShiftC in Morning:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Morning shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))
                elif ShiftC in Evening:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Evening shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))
                elif ShiftC in Night:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Night shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))


            def Evening():
                Evening = []
                Night = []
                Morning = []
                x=1
                y=2
                z=3
                for i in range(99999):
                    Evening.append(float(x+3*i))
                    Night.append(float(y+3*i))
                    Morning.append(float(z+3*i))
                if ShiftC in Morning:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Morning shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))
                elif ShiftC in Evening:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Evening shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))
                elif ShiftC in Night:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Night shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))

            def Night():
                x = 1
                y = 2
                z = 3
                Night = [x]
                Morning = [y]
                Evening = [z]
                for i in range(1, 99999):
                    Night.append(int(x + 3 * i))
                    Morning.append(int(y + 3 * i))
                    Evening.append(int(z + 3 * i))
                if ShiftC in Morning:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Morning shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))
                elif ShiftC in Evening:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Evening shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))
                elif ShiftC in Night:
                    sg.popup("You will be on Night shift at requested date: {}".format(date_entry))

            if values["morning"] == True:
                SelectShift = "morning"
            elif values["evening"] == True:
                SelectShift = "evening"
            elif values["night"] == True:
                SelectShift = "night"

            date_entry = values["Date"]
            Dayoff1 = values["Day_Off"]
            year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('.'))
            date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
            TotalD = (datetime.date(2021, 1, 9).toordinal() - date1.toordinal()) * -1
            ShiftC = math.ceil(TotalD / 35)
            if SelectShift.lower() == "morning":
                Morning()
                Days_Off()
            elif SelectShift.lower() == "evening":
                Evening()
                Days_Off()
            elif SelectShift.lower() == "night":
                Night()
                Days_Off()
except Exception as e:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    sg.Print(f'An error happened.  Here is the info:', e, tb)
    sg.popup_error(f'AN EXCEPTION OCCURRED!', e, tb)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the

```
window.close()
```

used in line 24. Moved it in line 111 and this works like a charm right now.